# How to clear content of button click after each click and generate new

Tags: javascript, html

I have done a lot of research and can't seem to find an answer or my search terms are not good.

I am building an app that uses an `API` to get and show data, inside an `HTML` body generated using `document.createElement` method. I have a textbox and form button that, when text is entered and button clicked, retrieves the data and builds it into the `HTML`.

This was going well at one stage, when I entered text and clicked the button multiple times the `HTML` content will be replaced every time. But now when I enter text and click the button multiple times the `HTML` generate every time and each `HTML` content display below each other instead of clearing the current `HTML` and generating it anew.

If someone can please just look at my code and see where I am going wrong it would be appreciated.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4d01Lo85/. (use 'Accio' and/or 'Apparate' for examples in textbox)

```js
const spells = 'https://www.potterapi.com/v1/spells/?key=$2a$10$ETe09n075yUIX1L.Rd0Yx.lkB9svshYSg76BhZxIjrfrvp9/my5YG';
const spellBtn = document.querySelector('.spell-btn');
const spellTextBox = document.querySelector('#spell-text');
let spellContainer = document.querySelector('.spell-container');

function getJson(url, callback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      return callback(data);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}

function createElements(type, parent, elementClass, elementID) {
  let element = document.createElement(type);
  parent.appendChild(element);
  element.className = elementClass;
  element.id = elementID;
  return element;
}

function generateSpellBody(data) {
  let spellBody = createElements('div', spellContainer, 'spell-cast', 'spell-cast');
  let spanclass = '';
  let error = 'Sorry, this is not a spell, or try again.';
  let spellName = '';
  let spellEffect = '';
  let spellType = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].spell === spellTextBox.value) {
      spellName = data[i].spell;
      spellEffect = `Type: ${data[i].effect}`;
      spellType = `Effect: ${data[i].type}`;
      spanclass += spellType;
      error = '';
      break;
    }
  }

  if (spellName === spellTextBox.value) {
    let spellRes = createElements('p', spellBody, spanclass.toLowerCase(), 'spell-res');
    let spellTypeDiv = createElements('p', spellBody, spanclass.toLowerCase(), 'spell-type');
    let spellEffPar = createElements('p', spellBody, spanclass.toLowerCase(), 'spell-info');
    spellRes.innerHTML = spellName;
    spellTypeDiv.innerHTML = spellType;
    spellEffPar.innerHTML = spellEffect;
  }

  let errorMsg = createElements('h3', spellBody, 'spell-error-message', 'error');
  errorMsg.innerHTML = error;
}

spellBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let numbers = /^([^0-9]*)$/;
  let filledIn = true;

  if (!filledIn) {
    return;
  }
  if (!spellTextBox.value.match(numbers)) {
    filledIn = false;
  }
  if (!filledIn) {
    console.log('number alert');
  } else {
    getJson(spells, generateSpellBody);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 spell-container">
  <form method='get'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="spell-text" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter spell">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="spell-btn btn btn-default btn-light">Do spell</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where and to what do you append `spellRes`, `spellTypeDiv` and `spellEffPar`

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or other available tools like [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) for us.

Comment: @SMAKSS sorry, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/4d01Lo85/

Comment: @mplungjan I added a fiddle so just look at it, I updated my post to include examples to insert into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing too much code in this case. Try this

I moved the form outside the container and empty the container if it is spellcontainer

```js
const spells = 'https://www.potterapi.com/v1/spells/?key=$2a$10$ETe09n075yUIX1L.Rd0Yx.lkB9svshYSg76BhZxIjrfrvp9/my5YG';
const spellBtn = document.querySelector('.spell-btn');
const spellTextBox = document.querySelector('#spell-text');
let spellContainer = document.querySelector('.spell-container');

function getJson(url, callback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      return callback(data);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}

function createElements(type, parent, elementClass, elementID) {
  if (parent === spellContainer) parent.innerHTML="";
  let element = document.createElement(type);
  parent.appendChild(element);
  element.className = elementClass;
  element.id = elementID;
  return element;
}

function generateSpellBody(data) {
  let spellBody = createElements('div', spellContainer, 'spell-cast', 'spell-cast');
  let spanclass = '';
  let error = 'Sorry, this is not a spell, or try again.';
  let spellName = '';
  let spellEffect = '';
  let spellType = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].spell === spellTextBox.value) {
      spellName = data[i].spell;
      spellEffect = `Type: ${data[i].effect}`;
      spellType = `Effect: ${data[i].type}`;
      spanclass += spellType;
      error = '';
      break;
    }
  }

  if (spellName === spellTextBox.value) {
    let spellRes = createElements('p', spellBody, spanclass.toLowerCase(), 'spell-res');
    let spellTypeDiv = createElements('p', spellBody, spanclass.toLowerCase(), 'spell-type');
    let spellEffPar = createElements('p', spellBody, spanclass.toLowerCase(), 'spell-info');
    spellRes.innerHTML = spellName;
    spellTypeDiv.innerHTML = spellType;
    spellEffPar.innerHTML = spellEffect;
  }

  let errorMsg = createElements('h3', spellBody, 'spell-error-message', 'error');
  errorMsg.innerHTML = error;
}

spellBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let numbers = /^([^0-9]*)$/;
  let filledIn = true;

  if (!filledIn) {
    return;
  }
  if (!spellTextBox.value.match(numbers)) {
    filledIn = false;
  }
  if (!filledIn) {
    console.log('number alert');
  } else {
    getJson(spells, generateSpellBody);
  }
});
```

```html
  <form method='get'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="spell-text" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter spell">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="spell-btn btn btn-default btn-light">Do spell</button>
  </form>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 spell-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying something similar to `parent.innerHTML=""` but inside the `generateSpellBody ` function the whole time! Thanks